# How to add a subtitle field to a block view?

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I want to add an additional subtitle to a block view in Drupal 8. For example my View would be showing News on the site. So I want the title to be 'News' and then a subtitle underneath 'My Subtitle'. Then the list of news would follow. How would I do this? Can i add additional fields just like with custom blocks?

In the end it should look something like that:

```
    <div class="content-section-heading">
       <h2 class="content-section-subtitle"> Subheadline </h2>
       <h1 class="content-section-title"> Headline </h1>
    </div>
   <div>
      Block Content
   </div>
```

Comment: I added some HTML Code to illustrate the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a `Global: Text area` in the **`HEADER`** and type your Subtitle there.

[image]

You can use FULL HTML and wrap it in a div class or ID so you can do some CSS work on it.

> Can i add additional fields just like with custom blocks?

You can add fields to your view

[image]

or attach another view that contains fields in the **`FOOTER`**, but fields in views and fields in custom blocks are totally different.

Comment: Is it possible to have the subtitle field globaly for all blocks and views? And set a value for each block in a form. Just like with the title field?

Comment: @Benedikt not out of the box. You would have to build a custom module to add this feature.

Comment: There is no module built for this already I guess?

Comment: @Benedikt not for D8.